# Apple Music & AVAudioEngine in Swift

Tags: swift, avaudioengine, apple-music

How can we access songs in the Apple Music library with `AVAudioPlayerNode`/`AVAudioEngine` for playback and processing?

I have asked this question in [Apple forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/126054#126054).

Comment: So the purpose of _this_ post is to complain that Apple hasn't responded to your _other_ post on their forum?

Comment: More likelihood that Apple will pay attention to the burning question.

Comment: Do you specifically mean the cloud streaming library, or the library on the device?

Comment: I mean on device

Comment: Does this work with MPMusicPlayerController for non-apple music songs in the user's iTunes library?

Answer (score 5):

"Apple Music" may refer to:

- the music streaming service
- its iOS client (known as "Music")
- its macOS client, which doubles as a local media management and playback app (formerly known as iTunes, known as "Music" as of macOS Catalina).

Due to DRM restrictions it is not possible to play tracks from the Apple Music catalogue downloaded onto your device from the Apple Music macOS or iOS clients. However you can play audio files you *own* and which you've [*synced* onto your device using the macOS Music app or the Finder app](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT210611), as follows:

1. Add the `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` key to your Info.plist file, and its corresponding value
2. Setup your `AVAudioSession` and `AVAudioEngine`
3. Find the URL of the media item you want to play (you can use `MPMediaPickerController` like in the example below or you can make your own `MPMediaQuery`)
4. Create an `AVAudioFile` from that URL
5. Create an `AVAudioPlayerNode` set to play that `AVAudioFile`
6. Connect the player node to the engine's output node

```swift
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let engine = AVAudioEngine()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .music)
        mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
        mediaPicker.showsItemsWithProtectedAssets = false // These items usually cannot be played back
        mediaPicker.showsCloudItems = false // MPMediaItems stored in the cloud don't have an assetURL
        mediaPicker.delegate = self
        mediaPicker.prompt = "Pick a track"
        present(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func startEngine(playFileAt: URL) {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)

            let avAudioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: playFileAt)
            let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()

            engine.attach(player)
            engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: avAudioFile.processingFormat)

            try engine.start()
            player.scheduleFile(avAudioFile, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)
            player.play()
        } catch {
            assertionFailure(String(describing: error))
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {
    func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
        guard let item = mediaItemCollection.items.first else {
            print("no item")
            return
        }
        print("picking \(item.title!)")
        guard let url = item.assetURL else {
            return print("no url")
        }

        dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
            self?.startEngine(playFileAt: url)
        }
    }

    func mediaPickerDidCancel(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note for anyone not getting a back the url from certain tracks make sure to set  mediaPicker.showsItemsWithProtectedAssets = false so that the picker omits DRM protected content, that you can not load into AVAudioPlayerNode.

Comment: Cheers @SamBing. I've updated the code accordingly.